# Implementing the Ace Code Editor in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, ace-editor

I am trying to make a code editor using JavaFX and want to use [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/). I saw an earlier post that used WebView to achieve this but I am a little lost on how to set up my project structure beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a very minimal implementation with JavaFX's WebView and the Ace editor.

To get started, I'll just use a few required js files from the Ace [repository](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master):

- `editor.html`, this is the main entry. Download from [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/editor.html), and add it to the resources folder, like: `src/main/resources/ace/editor.html`.
- `mode-java.js`, download from [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/mode-java.js), and add it to resources: `src/main/resources/ace/js/mode-java.js`.
- `theme-eclipse.js`, download from [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/theme-eclipse.js), and add it to resources: `src/main/resources/ace/js/theme-eclipse.js`.

Note that the above project structure corresponds with the use of Maven or Gradle build tools. To get started, I used this [project](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/CommandLine/Non-modular/Gradle/hellofx) as a reference.

Now edit the `editor.html` file, and replace the existing scripts with:

```
<script src="js/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/java");
</script>
```

Optionally, replace the javascript function with some java code, like:

```
<pre id="editor">package com.ace.editor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AceEditor {

    /*
     * This is a demo
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}</pre>
```

Finally, in your JavaFX code, add a `WebView` control, and load the editor:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(); 
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/ace/editor.html").toExternalForm());
Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 600, 400);
...
```

Note that you will need to add the `javafx.web` module. This is using Gradle, but the same could be done with Maven.

```
javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.web' ]
}
```

Build and run the project, and you should get the code editor:

[image: Ace editor]

More functionality can be added by modifying the `editor.html` file, and adding more js files, to extend the editor options. For instance, [this](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/demo/statusbar.html) shows you can add a statusbar.

**EDIT**

This is my project structure:

[image]

(It uses FXML as well, but doesn't change anything of the above).

Comment: Were editor.html, mode-java.js, and theme-eclipse.js the only files you included into the Java project?

Comment: related to ACE, yes, just those 3. That should get you started, but there are many more that you can include, of course.

Comment: I was able to get the editor.html file showing, but the entirety of `<script src="js/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/java");
</script>` had no impact (commenting out changed nothing). The Webview simply showed the pre-existing code, but it is immutable and has no color scheme. Adding the ace.js file suppressed errors showing in the 3 files, but since it still didn't work (same problems), I suspect that I am still missing something else......

Comment: @GL I've edited my answer with the project structure. Make sure you have the same, at least within your resources.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just restarted my IDE and it started working without any new changes, not sure what was going on.